# Run python 3.6 on 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

We have python scripts developed using py3.6, but while deploying we found that liunx machines are on 2.7.

Is there any way we still execute our 3.6 version scripts on 2.7 ?

I found the other way of running , but not getting the leads for 3.6 on 2.7.

Comment: Not directly that i know of. Depending on how complex the scripts are, you maybe be able to just try to run them, and fix the errors as they come up.

Comment: You can get some limited upgrades with the `__future__` package.  As a general solution, you have to upgrade your installation.

Comment: "We found [while deploying] that Linux machines are on 2.7." --- This is why it's important to know about your target environment. Oops, now you'll have to rewrite code, especially if you can't install Python 3 on those machines. I'm using 2.3 currently, and I had to learn a *lot* of tough lessons: 2.3 doesn't even have the `set` built-in.

Comment: It may be easier to upgrade the machines to python 3 if at all possible, python 2 is end of life at this point.

Comment: If you can you should install pyenv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for switch your python version

Comment: Thank you for your time and inputs ! appreciate the responses..

Comment: If your scripts have shbang lines or other references to the interpreter, they should be to `python3`, not `python`, and they should be referencing it via `/usr/bin/env python3` rather than a hardcoded path. (The first half of that might change after 2020, but it’s the current official recommendation, and the one the Linux distros are working to support.) That might be all you need—many distros come with both versions. (Although you may get 3.5 or 3.4, which might still be a problem.) if not, `python3` is probably an apt-get/yum/whatever away.

Comment: Also, you should consider using virtualenvs for deployment, so you’re relying on whichever Python is activated in the current shell (which you can set up on a per-program basis), rather than which is the default on the system (which you often can’t easily change). And there are other advantages that can make this worth doing even if you’re, e.g., deploying fixed docket containers and not even touching the system’s interpreters.

Comment: But anyway, you can’t in general run Python 3.6 code in Python 2.7. If you could, Python 3 wouldn’t need to exist in the first place. Sometimes it’s worth writing (or porting existing code to) dual-version code using libraries like `six`, but you still can’t take advantage of major features like yield from, async, f-strings, etc. that were added after 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

One think we can do about running the the code written in Python3  on Python2 compiler. Convert the python3 files to Python2 files by using the package 
`python-3to2`

Install(for ubuntu, for Redhat use yum)
`sudo apt install python-3to2`
and then Run
`3to2 -w python_3_file.py`
It will modify the file to python 2 compatible and then you can start execute using Python2